# Can anyone help me with this error ELK/Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, elastic-stack

ERROR

Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance,

> {:url=>#http://localhost:9200/>,
>   :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError,
>   :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable:
>   [http://localhost:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection
>   refused (Connection refused)"}

Here are my files.

Logstash.conf:

```
input 
     {
       tcp 
           {
            port => 5000 
            }
       } 
        output { 
               elasticsearch 
                 { 
               hosts => "elasticsearch:9200" 
                 } 
         }

elasticsearch.yml:

cluster.name: "docker-cluster" 
network.host: 0.0.0.0 
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1 
discovery.type: single-node 
xpack.security.enabled: false 
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false 
xpack.ml.enabled: false 
xpack.graph.enabled: false 
xpack.watcher.enabled: false

logstash.yml

http.host: "0.0.0.0"
path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false

Kibana.yml:

server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.url:http://elasticsearch:9200
xpack.security.enabled: false
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
xpack.ml.enabled: false
xpack.graph.enabled: false
xpack.reporting.enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused might be an indication of the firewall blocking that port or service, make sure your firewall settings allow the service your trying to reach. In Linux there is a GUI interface for the firewall To start this application, either select System → Administration → Firewall from the panel, or type system-config-firewall at a shell prompt. If your in windows just type firewall in the search box at the bottom left corner and click on firewall advance settings. Try enabling port 9200 and if elasitcshearch is a service running also enable it through firewall.

***In Linux you can try this to unblock port 9200:**

firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9200/tcp

firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9300/tcp

***Start the service:**

sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service

sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

***Then enable the service in the firewall:**

sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --elasticsearch.service

firewall-cmd --reload

Comment: I have added 3 ports 5601,9200/tcp & 9300/tcp, but it throws me the same error. Do I need to make any another change...

Comment: Yes the elastic search service needs to be enabled in the filrewall, first start the service: sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload; 
sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service; 
sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service; then enable the service in the firewall, sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --elasticsearch.service

Comment: @Farn see my edited solution, I added more steps that might help you

Comment: I am Working on Windows environment, can you help me with the same commands on Windows?.

Additionally I'm getting response from the elasticsearch on localhost:9200  and kibana localhost:5601/app/kibana on the browsers. But I'm still seeing the connection error on the log file

Comment: I solved this issue I have changed the hosts as hosts => "elasticsearch"  in salesforce.conf file instead of localhots

Comment: I have one more issue, when I create a new record in the object I cant view in Kibana dono why....